# How to send a graph (highcharts) via email in django using email templates?

Tags: django, highcharts

One of my requirement is to send a weekly graph report to the team members. For that I am using highcharts.js to display graphs on the UI. I need to send the same graph in mail using django.

Is it possible to include internal css and javascript/jquery in the email template?
In my case internal css and js are displaying in the email. Is there a way to send graphs in email using django?

Comment: How about using Highcharts export to generate an image you can include instead?

Comment: Convert it to image

Comment: Can I create the graph on the fly, with get_template() and render()?